# Spring @Primary not working

Tags: java, spring

I have a simple configuration

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationUtil {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Profile("apple")
    Fruit apple(){
        return new Apple();
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("banana")
    Fruit banana(){
        return new Banana();
    }

}
```

In application.properties if I use `spring.profiles.active=apple` or banana the proper one gets autowired but if i remove it I have the error:

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in basicspringexample.basicspringexample.MainUtil required a bean of type 'basicspringexample.basicspringexample.comp.Fruit' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'basicspringexample.basicspringexample.comp.Fruit' in your configuration.
```

The bean gets called by a simple @Service annotated class

```
@Service
public class MainUtil {

    private Fruit fruit;

    @Autowired
    public MainUtil(Fruit fruit) {
        this.fruit = fruit;
        System.out.println(fruit.print());
    }

}
```

Isn't `@Primary` supposed to display the annotated bean when there's not specification in `spring.profiles.active` ? Or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: And why should it? You don't specify a profile, both beans are dependent on a profile... So if you don't specify one of the profiles non of the beans will be loaded.

Comment: So @Primary gives precedence to a bean if their profile is the same ? I miss-read the documentation, thank for the clarification

Comment: No it will give precedence if multiple instances of a bean of certain type are found. How that happens has nothing to do with profiles.

Comment: Yes i understand now

Answer (score 2):

#### Why isn't @Primary working as I expect?

First, the bean configurations gets filtered by `@Profile`. Only after this, `@Primary` will kick in *if* multiple beans of the same type is found.

This is why, after the filtering of `no profile`, no bean of type `Fruit` is left and Spring will complain.